When I get data from procedure in PostgreSQL, it shows not exist although it exist?
I created a stored procedure in PostgreSQL like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE app_sec."app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants"(
    IN p_tenant_cur refcursor,
    OUT p_status integer,
    OUT p_status_desc text)

I try to get data by calling this stored procedure in PostgreSQL using this C# code, but I get an error:

42883: function app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants(refcursor, integer, text) does not exist

on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
public ResponseStatus GetTenantList()
{
    ResponseStatus response = new ResponseStatus();

    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string cmdString = "";

        OpenDB();

        string sqlstr = @"
        DO $$
        DECLARE
            p_tenant_cur REFCURSOR;
            p_status INTEGER;
            p_status_desc TEXT;
        BEGIN
            -- Call the stored procedure to initialize the cursor
            PERFORM app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants(p_tenant_cur, p_status, p_status_desc);
        END $$;";

        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlstr, postcon))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute the DO block to set up the cursor
        }

        // Now fetch the results from the cursor
        string fetchSql = "FETCH ALL FROM p_tenant_cur;";

        using (var fetchCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(fetchSql, postcon))
        {
            using (NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(fetchCommand))
            {
                adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "p_tenant_cur");
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }

        response.ds = ds;

        CloseDB();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return response;
}

I try to confirm if stored procedure not exist or created using C#
but it show me it exist using
string checkProcSql = @"
            SELECT proname
    FROM pg_proc
    JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_proc.pronamespace = pg_namespace.oid
    WHERE proname = 'app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants'
    AND nspname = 'app_sec'; ";

using (var checkCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(checkProcSql, postcon))
{
    var result = checkCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Stored procedure does not exist.");
    }
}

Updated post
I try as below but not working and give me error

42883: function app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants(refcursor, integer, text) does not exist

 public ResponseStatus GetTenantList()
        {
            ResponseStatus response = new ResponseStatus();
            try
            {
              

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                OpenDB();
              
                using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT app_sec.\"app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants\"('p_tenant_cur', 'p_status', 'p_status_desc');", postcon))
                {
                    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "p_tenant_cur");
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                    }
                }

                response.ds = ds;

                

                CloseDB();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Status = "0";
                response.StatusDesc = Common.GetStringWithoutQuate(ex.Message);
            }
            return response;
        }



From here Identifiers: Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less portable. 2) Why are you supplying values to OUT arguments in the procedure signature?  If you want to do that should they not be INOUT?


Why do you use a DO statement for this? And when using horrible names like this for objects like procedures, you have to put them between double quotes ". I would avoid names like this.

so how to fix give me solution without do and i will apply it

can you show me another way instead of using do can you help me please

Remove the $ from the name.

Or put it between double quotes forever: "app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants"

i can't remove it because this is related to db. admin
can you try another solution

can you show me in code how to do put it between double quotes forever: "app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants"

No, I really think you can put one double quote before the name and another behind it. You have to escape it correctly since your entire SQL statement is also between double quotes, but that's another problem. But you'd better remove the $ from the name.

can you please show me how to do it

are this what you mean
string sqlstr = @"
DO $$
DECLARE
p_tenant_cur REFCURSOR;
p_status INTEGER;
p_status_desc TEXT;
BEGIN
            PERFORM app_sec.""app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants""(p_tenant_cur, p_status, p_status_desc);

            
            OPEN p_tenant_cur FOR SELECT * FROM app_sec.""app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants""(p_tenant_cur, p_status, p_status_desc);
        END $$;";


can any one helping answer question

I did not look at the error function app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants(refcursor, integer, text) does not exist close enough. The key is function. The code is failing because it is looking for a function not a procedure and it is looking for a function because you do  PERFORM app_perm_sp_pkg$get_all_tenants ....  PERFORM is equivalent to SELECT which is why it is looking for a function. A procedure needs to use CALL. Either change the procedure to a function or use CALL.

can you reply me on post answer with modifications i don't have more knowledgae about postgree
